# Can app targeted Android 3.1 carry the old WebView whatever Android version is installed?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-play, android-webview, android-api-levels

From Android 4.4 the WebView is changed, and from Android 7.0 it is Chrome engine and not the WebView.

I see that my app is broken with newest Android versions because it uses many features of old WebView, it's targeted Android 3.1 and needs quirksmode, but quirksmode is not enough because some behaviour is unpredictable.

Now I am asking here if it is possible to compile my app so it carries the old WebView whatever the version of the Android OS.

Comment: It is more than 3 years since Android 4.4 release ... **and you still do not move your application forward?** ... less than 20% of devices on google store has android lower than 4.4 ...

Comment: @Selvin You seem to be right but the changes are unreasonable if you consider that users can install a published 3.1 app on new devices and lose its features. It's non-sense for me to lose legacy apps, they cannot easily updated; sometimes no resources are available for further development. So why are they installable? The compatibility is lost because of a Google decision not by their fault.

Comment: There are two choices either you will rewrite the app or try to use one of the few libraries(embedded webkits) which implements WebView... The problem with second option is that you have to try because there in no guarantee that will work either.